# Issues with Amazon Amplify. Failed to fetch Admin Credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

Hello StackOverflow family:

I have been beating my head on this error.  I am trying to perform an **amplify init** from terminal and I get this error.

```
Failed to fetch Amplify Admin Credentials
init failed
Error: TypeError:  Cannot read property 'idToken" of undefined
```

I have gone in and removed the aws cli and everything associated with it.  Reinstalled it from scratch. Put in a new account with access token and secret key and still get the above error.   What could I do to bypass this error.  Any assistance would be helpful.  When I logon to the admin console.  My app of course does not show up.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you include the code where the error is coming from?

Comment: Are you requesting my swift code

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar issue with the latest version of amplify cli, switching back to an old version fixed the problem for me:

`yarn global add @aws-amplify/cli@4.36.2`

Comment: I was using npm so I tried following command. 

npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli@4.36.2

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across the same issue on OSX with safari. Using Chrome resolved the issue for me.

When prompted to login to the amplify admin console, simply copy the link into chrome and login with your user credentials. You will have had to create a user in the Admin UI Console beforehand.